# Log4jdbc and underlying connection

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm using [Log4jdbc-log4j2](https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc-log4j2/) to log database activity but it makes it impossible to use database specific methods. How do I access underlying `org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection`? This code

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:log4jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432//my_db", "user", "password";
BaseConnection pgConn = (BaseConnection) conn;
```

throws invalid cast exception, naturally.

Comment: which driver u r using

Comment: I don't explicitly load any drivers, but I guess they are `net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy` and `org.postgresql.Driver`